# How to properly approach a GitHub workflow as a solo developer?

Tags: version-control, git, solo-development

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Are there advantages to using a DVCS for a solo developer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10791/are-there-advantages-to-using-a-dvcs-for-a-solo-developer)
> [As a sole developer (for now), how should I be using Git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114258/as-a-sole-developer-for-now-how-should-i-be-using-git)

I'm a solo developer, and I've been quite comfortable with SVN for a number of years.

My workflow has been the following

1. create a project on dev workstation and make changes
2. commit to subversion
3. pull project to dev notebook and make changes
4. commit changes
5. wash, rinse, repeat (no branches)

Now I've recently pushed my first open project to GitHub, and I really like how it all works.

I'm wondering however, what is the best approach to using a DVCS as a solo eveloper. Should one follow the same workflow as SVN and work exclusively on the master, or is it a good idea as a solo developer to fork the project for my two (or possibly more) dev machines?

Any advice on how to approach a GitHub workflow as a solo developer would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### EDIT

One thing I've come up with as I continue to wrap my head around this problem is the fact that the "master" repo should only be for fully functioning code.

Therefore I should create a single "working" branch and push it back and forth between my two dev computers. When I feel that I've got the next iteration of fully functioning code, I proceed to push it to the master, but never work directly with the master code.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not looking for the benefits of a DVCS, I'm looking for the best approach in using a DVCS as a solo developer.

Comment: @JoshK, I've followed up over at [meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/consider-reopening-my-question)

Comment: linking few prior questions that [were suggested](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3078/31260) as potentially helpful at meta: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46039/git-in-non-distributed-independent-lone-programming-best-practices http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89025/what-should-be-the-workflow-with-a-git-repository http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37564/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-development-with-git